# How to check which jobs use a particular IN condition in Control-M

Tags: jobs, control-m

I am using Control M Enterprise manager to track jobs.
I have a job with OUT-condition as 'X_OK'.
i am not sure if/where a job is using this as IN-condition.
Is there any way i can search for jobs which have this particular condition as IN-condition.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest Control M workload automation there is an option for searching for jobs having particular IN or OUT condition. Just type the condition and search.

Answer (score 1):

- Download the physical data model of your version of Control-M: ftp://ftp.bmc.com/pub/control-m/opensystem/DB_Schemas/
- Connect to your Control-M database
- To search input conditions look in the tables def_job and def_lnki_p
- To search output conditions look in the tables def_job and def_lnko_p

Example:

```
-- Display all job names that use the IN condition "aaabbbccc"
SELECT 
  job_name
FROM 
  emuser.def_lnki_p, 
  emuser.def_job 
WHERE 
  def_lnki_p.table_id = def_job.table_id AND
  def_lnki_p.job_id = def_job.job_id AND
  def_lnki_p.version_serial = def_job.version_serial AND
  LOWER(def_lnki_p.condition) LIKE '%aaabbbccc%';
```

Answer (score -1):

All the jobs that are set up in Control M will show the arrows that are connected to each other. So, If X is connected to different jobs, then that will be shown through the out going arrows from X.
Also, if you are finding it difficult to find out this way, do the followign on job X, and you can find out jobs that use the X's OUT condition as their IN condition -
Right Click (on Job X) -> Branch Menu -> Successor -> (The jobs displayed here use the X's OUT-condition as their IN-condition)

Comment: job A using job B's OUT condition need not be its successor. so this method is not always applicable.

Comment: We call it successor mostly when a job runs on completion of a previous job. In the above case this is right. Unless Job X completes, any job that have X as IN-CONDITION will not run.

Comment: I think you did not get my question. Anyways I have figured this out.

Answer (score -1):

Use Neighborhood option . It will give u list of Successor and predecessor jobs